# bootstrap 4 pull-xs-right not working as expected

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this html using [bootstrap 4 utilities](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/) to pull the buttons to the right of the screen.  And it does do this.

However, the buttons do not push down the content below it as expected. They end up overlayed on top of the content below.

If I do not use `pull-xs-right` then the buttons are left aligned, but they do push the items below.

Is there some other class I need to apply?

```
       <div class="pull-xs-right">
            <button click.delegate="saveEdit()"
                    type="submit"
                    class="k-button k-primary">
                Save
            </button>
            <button click.delegate="cancel()"
                    class="k-button">
                Cancel
            </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: share your work on jsfiddle .

Comment: pull-xs-right only adds `float: right` so your div stays a block at 100% width

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4 `.float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none}` classes were added for responsive floats, and replaced `.pull-left` and `.pull-right`.

That means:

`.pull-right` was replaced by `.float-right`

`.pull-left` was replaced by `.float-left`

`.pull-xs-right` is wrong, replace `.pull` by `.float` the `xs` between pull and right stands for extra small which determines the size of the element. The following are the options to change the element size: `{xs,sm,md,lg,xl}` where `xs` = extra small, `sm` = small, `md` = medium, `lg` = large and `xl` = extra large

See: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: Thanks! I've lost 2 hours of my life on this... I'll look for migration docs sooner next time...

Comment: in https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css there is no `float-xs-right` but start from `sm` such as `float-sm-right`

Comment: Sorry for the delay on marking this as the correct answer. I somehow missed this earlier.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above float replaces pull. So `.float-right` replaces `.pull-right` and `.float-left` replaces `.pull-right`.  You can add -`{sm,md,lg,xl}` for different breakpoints for example `.float-md-right` will break on medium-sized screens. If you leave off the size then it will not break and will always float in the direction indicated.