# pull-right replacement in bootstrap 4 does not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

I have [read](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#utilities) that the `pull-right` class has been removed
and in its place there are classes such as `.float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none}` - as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542435/bootstrap-4-pull-xs-right-not-working-as-expected) too.

but i cant get it to work.
I have setup a demo at 
https://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/x8Lhmajc/1/
you will see the word "menu" on the top left, which has a drop down attached. that is supposed to be floated to the right
but as you can see its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to make it work with your situation using classes **col and float-right** together. Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5XoPbBJeAYPntJ8AMeek?p=preview) and in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8Lhmajc/2/). But usually, just float-right is enough.

```
 <div class="col float-right">                
     <div class="dropdown actionButtons float-right">
     //your content
   </div>
</div>
```

And if you need to move only menu, wrap **col-sm-12**(md, lg what you need) and use **float-right** in example (see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukrogt5q/)).

```
 <div class="col-md-12"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but i need the menu icon at the *far* right - after all the other columns. even if i use `col-sm-12 float-right` instead of your `col float right` - i do get it at the far right, but all the other `col-*` elements then break onto the next line. maybe i can fix this with some negative margin, but it still sounds like a work-around rather than a clean solution. What do you suggest?

Comment: it depends what is you next col-sm- value. For example if its col-sm-10 use not col-sm-12 but col-sm-2. 12-10 = 2

Comment: It's bootsrap if you use col-sm-12 it will take the whole row. but if you use less it make them in one row

Comment: for example col-sm-12 and col-sm-12 will be 2 rows. but col-sm-6 and col-sm-6 will be one row

Comment: Understood, thanks. i had made a mistake getting up to 12 :)  
but this is what i have now: https://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/x8Lhmajc/4/ - still no float.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a little late but I did have a hard time also. Whenever i managed to place the columns under the "row" class, nothing would let me pull right. I guess this works and here is my solution;

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col order-last">
      Whatever
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the `.row` div is now in `display:flex`, that's why the float does not work correctly!
you can

1) wrap the content in a `<div class="col-sm-12></div>` (that's the right way to use the grid: if you don't use the `.col-something` you'll end up with negative margins and part of your content is not visible)

2) use one of the flex utilities listed here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/ like the class `flex-row-reverse`

Comment: Thank you! Questions: for your option `(1)` - do you mean to wrap the *menu* item in `<div class="col-sm-12></div>`? like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/x8Lhmajc/3/.  and regarding your option `(2)`, my issue that the existing col order is fine, i just need the menu element to be on the far right

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems correct. you must always use `.col-something` inside `.row`, because the latter has negative margins (for the grid construction)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/x8Lhmajc/6/ is the updated one. the issue in this, is that the menu lands up being in its own row - whereas it should be part of the column structure

Comment: you are trying to do something like this? https://codepen.io/erredeco/pen/aLdwpG 
I don't know what you are doing, but it seems to me that the data you are trying to display could be better displayed with a table